# Dynamic text based on user filter selection on Google Data Studio

Tags: google-cloud-platform, data-visualization, tableau-api, looker-studio

I want to create a text description which has dynamic text based on user filter selection on Google Data Studio.  The text should highlight the filters selected by users currently and will change based on future selections. Its pretty easy to do so on other BI tools such as PowerBI or Tableau. Wondering about GDS

Answer (score 1):

You can use table by removing the header, pagination, row number, and metric

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30571114)